# How to run a jar before compiling with Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Okay so I have had several issues with running a jar before the project was build but I've finally found a solution. The jar would generate translation files based on a cvs file.

If I run `./gradlew taskname` the project is build, the script runs and the files are generated. If I run from Android studio everything is fine too but if I run `./gradlew` (no target) the project will be build and the script will seem to run but the files that the jar would generate doesn't appear!!!

Any ideas why this is?

**Note**: The jar uses `mkdirs` and works without any issues.

**Gradle code**:

```
task translationsTask(type: Exec) {
    println("Running jar from gradle with shell script.")
    workingDir rootDir
    commandLine './test.sh'
}
preBuild.dependsOn(translationsTask)

android {
...
}
```

Comment: *if I run ./gradlew (no target) the project will be build* : are you sure about that ? Because no task specified means no execution phase (just the configuration one which implies the message "Running jar from gradle with shell script." will be displayed)

Comment: @ToYonos Okay could you send me in a direction so I get a better understanding about this. I don't get why the print would get out but the commandline wont be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Gradle` build has [three distinct phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases) including the configuration one and the execution one.

Your `translationsTask` task is an [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) task. `workingDir` and `commandLine` are here to configure it. These parameters will be used during the execution phase. The `println` statement written like this will be included in the configuration phase. The `doFirst` and`doLast` closures allow to add custom actions during the execution phase.

Here is your task with proper messages :

```
task translationsTask(type: Exec) {
    println("Configuring the translationsTask")
    workingDir rootDir
    commandLine './test.sh'
    doFirst {
            println("Running jar from gradle with shell script, before the command line")
    }
    doLast {
            println("Running jar from gradle with shell script, after the command line")
    }
}
```

Only calling `gradlew` will only display *Configuring the translationsTask* (no execution phase as no target task). Calling `gradlew taskname` will display all messages as there is a target task and the Android `preBuild` task is invoked (and so is `translationsTask` as `preBuild` depends on it)